# Docker "docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" script doesn't get executed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to get a "docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" script running. The scripts do get copied into the right folder: "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d", but it does not execute. Am I missing something? I thought that files in the "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" get executed automatically.

Please note that I'm using an Alpine version of PHP "FROM php:7-fpm-alpine".

"docker-compose.yml":

```
services:
    php:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./etc/docker/php/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ${PROJECT_PATH}/etc/docker/php/db-init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

db-init-scripts/crond.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

crond -l 2 -f
```

Answer (score 0):

This image does not support `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

You can use `ENTRYPOINT`. Just add to `Dockerfile`

`ENTRYPOINT sh crond.sh`

Comment: So as I expected when I use your approach it overwrites the original entrypoint which stops php-fpm from running. How to solve this?

Comment: @Twoez yes, this would overwrite defalut entrypoint in the image. Maybe you could explain more about your crond.sh script on how dose it work. Then people may come up with other solutions to deal with it.

Comment: @Bukharov Sergey how do you know if the image supports `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` or not?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your file has windows line endings (CRLF) where as in your container the expected lilne endings are unix style (LF). This will be the default if you are on a linux OS. In windows you can change this using Notepad++. Open each file and go to `Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF)`. That worked for me.